# Substituir número por string nos resultados

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT 
sum(pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS value, 
pedidos_lentes.solar AS label FROM pedidos 
JOIN pedidos_lentes ON pedidos_lentes.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido 
WHERE id_loja = 2
group by pedidos_lentes.solar
```

A coluna `label` retorna os valores 1 e 0, armazenados no banco. No resultado, é possível trocar esses valores por strings?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido:

```
SELECT 
sum(pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS value, 
CASE pedidos_lentes.solar WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS label 

FROM pedidos 

JOIN pedidos_lentes ON pedidos_lentes.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido 
WHERE id_loja = 2
group by pedidos_lentes.solar
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, vê se te ajuda:

```
SELECT 
sum(pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS value,
CAST(pedidos_lentes.solara as CHAR(1)) AS label,
JOIN pedidos_lentes ON pedidos_lentes.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido 
WHERE id_loja = 2
group by pedidos_lentes.solar
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas cabei usando CASE.